# mssql backup from certain date

Tags: sql-server, backup

My Clients Database have exceeded 250GB; hence it becomes a problem for me to take their backup onto our system and restore the DB.

What I want to know is that, is there a way for me to fetch the changes done to the tables [I can identify the tables which have been modified] and get only that data?

In doing so, my time to download the DB will reduce as I will get only small Data which is modified and also my memory problem will be address where in I don't need to have additional space for the Backup file [size of backup file is huge].

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

My answer depends on you having columns in the database tables that you can use to filter the data on (something like `insert_date` or the like).

Create a temporary database with the same tables as the production db on the client machine, and insert only the datasets you need.

```
insert into client_filtered.huge_table
  select * from client_orig.huge_table
  where DATEDIFF(day,insert_date,getdate()) <= 7 --last 7 days
```

Then take a backup of that database.

If this is a regular task, automate it using SSIS.